# Solving for $u$ and $v$ in the 2D Jacobian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, coordinate-systems, jacobian

For a system I am studying, I know that the Jacobian for a transformation from variables $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ to $x$ and $y$ must be equal to a function $p(x,y)$ which is known. I want to find what $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are in terms of $p(x,y)$. The equation to solve is:

$$    p(x,y) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

where $p(x,y)$ is a known function and $u$ and $v$ depend on both $x$ and $y$. Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your problem is underdetermined. For example, any of the pairs $$(u, v) = \left(\int p dx, y \right), \left(\int p dy, -x \right), \left(x, \int p dy \right), \left(-y, \int p dx \right)$$ satisfy the problem. You need a second equation to uniquely determine $u, v$.

Comment: @MatthewCassel. Thank you for your advice. However, none of those solutions satisfy this problem in particular as I am looking for function $u$ and $v$ that depend on both x and y ($u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y$). This is because in the system I am studying $\rho(x,y)$ is rarely a separable function.

Comment: I think I was answering your question before you made the edit to include '$u$ and $v$ depend on both $x$ and $y$'. Anyway, my comment above still stands in that your system is underdetermined and you need another equation to get a unique solution. For example, all of the following satisfies the equation \begin{align} u &= x + y \text{ and $v$ solving } v_{y} - v_{x} = p \\ u &= x - y \text{ and $v$ solving } v_{y} + v_{x} = p \\ u &= - x + y \text{ and $v$ solving } - v_{y} - v_{x} = p \\ u &= - x - y \text{ and $v$ solving } - v_{y} + v_{x} = p \end{align}